# Binding class methods to external functions

Tags: python, oop, methods

I get an error when  trying to bind a class method to a function. Why?

```
def foo():
    print "Hello world"

class something(object):
    bar = foo

test = something()
test.bar()

TypeError: foo() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Also, if I am unable  to modify `foo`, can I do this adaptation from within the class definition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple way to do it is to wrap the function in a `staticmethod` inside A:

```
class A():
    bar = staticmethod(foo)

>>> test = A()
>>> test.bar()
Hello world
```

Comment: I like this solution, a lot. I guess this only works if I don't need to access the instance from within the function (but that was part of the assumption in my update)

Answer (score 6):

A class method in python always takes at least one argument, usually called `self`. This example is taken from the [official Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks):

```
# Function defined outside the class
def f1(self, x, y):
    return min(x, x+y)

class C:
    f = f1
    def g(self):
        return 'hello world'
    h = g
```

Note that both methods, regardless of whether they are defined outside or inside of the class, take `self` as an argument.

**Edit:** If you really can't change your `foo` function, then you can do something like this:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print "Hello World"
...
>>> class something(object):
...     def bar(self): foo()
...
>>> test = something()
>>> test.bar()
Hello World
```

Comment: Say I can't modify `foo` (or that I would prefer to not change it's signature). Can I do this adaptation from within the class definition?

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks @srgerg. I love Python.

Comment: See @BrenBarn for an interesting way of solving the "unable to change `foo`" problem

Comment: Yes I like BrenBarn's solution better.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a class method this way you pass the class instance as the first parameter.
When you call `test.bar` what in fact happens is more like `bar(test)`. You pass an argument to the method.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that when a python class calls one of it's methods it will pass in a `self` argument. You need to account for that in your code:

```
def foo(self):
    print ("Hello world")

class something(object):
    bar = foo

test = something()
test.bar()
```

You can read all about classes in the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

The easiest workaround to not passing in a `self` that I can think of is:

```
def foo():
    print ("Hello world")

class something(object):
    bar = [foo] # contains pointer to static method

test = something()
test.bar[0]() # calls the static method
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the OP to clarify that I am looking for a way of doing this that does not require modifying `foo`, but only the class definition itself.

Comment: @user815423426 Edited, There may be a better way but this one works, and i suppose you can add as many different functions as you want now.

Answer (score 1):

Class methods all have a first argument of the instance of the class.  So add a parameter to your function and it would work.

Answer (score 1):

The initial def creates a function object named `foo`. Since it's outside any class, it's just a function that takes no arguments. The assignment `bar = foo` just gives the new name `test.bar` to that same function object. The call `test.bar()`, however, assumes that bar is a class method, and passes the object `test` as the first argument to the method (the one that you would normally call `self`). You could call it as a static method with `something.bar()` and not get the error.